# Wordpress WP_QUERY with Category and Meta_key

Tags: wordpress

Currently i have 2 categories and 1 custom field

Category = CAT01 and CAT02 / ID's 1 and 2
Custom Field = Test01

What I want is the average of all values entered in my custom field (Test01), but from 1 category.

I'm new to Wordpress, but I got the following:

```
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array (
                    'category_id' => '1',
                    'meta_key' => 'Test01',
                    )
                 );
```

Without the category id it seems to do something, but not what I want.

Can anyone help me out with this, really appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I think using WP_Query adds needless overhead to this. I would do a custom SQL query (although you'd have to keep an eye on if WP changes their taxonomy DB structure in the future).

It would look something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$term = get_term(1, 'category');        //need the term_taxonomy_id, not always the same as term_id
$sqlQuery = "SELECT AVG(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Test01' AND post_id IN(SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '" . $term->term_taxonomy_id . "') ";
$avg = $wpdb->get_var($sqlQuery);
```